# Why i am getting this weird 500 error on a shared free server

Tags: php, hosting, internal-server-error

I have a project(idea) I've been developing my idea about 2 months and i am ready to release beta version of my application online.

Here is the thing my project 100% works fine in my '**localhost**' sever; and i have done my best to code standard. About an hour ago i upload my project on a free host server
http://www.serversfree.com/
for online testing. there is a weird '500' error, i have tried to track it so i start from beginning by putting "**die()**" statement in my codes. my project architecture is based on MVC model so every request gets pass through the **/public_html/default.php** file

I put a **die('test')** statement in the 1st line of my **/public_html/default.php** the obvious result is that for every request the *test* statement will flush-out and the php interpreter halts.

The problem is:
The result of this link
http://life-journal.bugs3.com/login
is different from this one
http://life-journal.bugs3.com/

Also i have viewed my site's log file but there was no error related to ***why i am getting this weird 500 error***

WHY and How can i solve this to run my online testing?

Thanks in advance.

---

The top part of my **/public_html/default.php** file is something like this(NOW) :

```
die('test');

session_start();

define(DEVELOPMENT, 'DEVELOPMENT');

define(PRODUCTION, 'PRODUCTION');
```

Comment: Do you have access to the error logs? Those would tell you what exactly goes wrong

Comment: This looks more like an apache error. Look at server error logs and see if you can find a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You go for http://life-journal.bugs3.com/default.php/login there is no error. My guess is that your hosting doesn't offer mod_rewrite but You should double check Your .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Check out the logs, possibly you ran into a PHP error. Also, it looks like, that error reporting is turned off, so for testing reasons, you can enable it on the first line of PHP code:

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

If error reporting is turned on (not common on production servers), then it is a server misconfiguration issue, and you should probably consult your hosting provider, otherwise the PHP error will lead you to the cause of the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you guys
You posts just reminded me that i have not changed my .htaccess

*RewriteRule ^(.+)$ **/index.php/$1***

to

*RewriteRule ^(.+)$ **/default.php/$1***

I am really thankful